# 'io is not defined' on client. included socket.io script tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am receiving these errors on the client:

```
GET /socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

In HTML

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

In client JS:

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

I have also tried adding the local server as some other posts suggested. (localhost:3000). I have used sockets before in this exact way without an error, so I am confused.

Comment: check your server side log, it might have an error during the start of the socket.

Answer (score 0):

Try access

```
http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

directly via your web browser to see it there's a javascript after you start socket.io server. If even your web browser cannot access it, client side has nothing to do with this problem. You must check your server side if it start correctly and port 3000 hasn't been used before by another process including your previous socket.io server that may not be killed from last session. Try

```
ps aux | grep node
```

in your shell to see if there's already node process or not before start new socket.io server.